# How to show inputs comes from front end form in repeater control at backend in octoberCMS

Tags: backend, octobercms

In Components,

default.htm

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var maxField = 3; //Input fields increment limitation
        var addButton = $('#add'); //Add button selector
        var wrapper = $('#main'); //Input field wrapper
         var i=1;
        var fieldHTML = '<div id="p_'+i+'" >' +
            'Name:<input type="text" name="name'+i+'" id="name'+i+'">' +
            ' <a href="" id="p_'+i+'" class="remove_button">remove</a>' +
            '</div>'; //New input field html
        var x = 1; //Initial field counter is 1

        //Once add button is clicked
        $(addButton).click(function(){


            //Check maximum number of input fields

           // alert("k");
            if(x < maxField){
                x++; //Increment field counter
                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); //Add field html
            }
            i++;
        });

        //Once remove button is clicked
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
            var proj_button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            //alert(edu_button_id);

            e.preventDefault();
            $("#"+ proj_button_id +"").remove();

            // $(this).parent('div').remove(); //Remove field html

            x--; //Decrement field counter
        });
    });
</script>



<form
        method="post"
        name="form" id="form" accept-charset="UTF8"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"  data-request="onEnter"  data-request-files>
    <input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onEnter">
    {{ form_token() }}
    {{ form_sessionKey() }}



    <div id="main">


    Name:<input type="text" name="name0" id="name0">
    <a  href="javascript:void(0);"   id="add">Add Another</a>
    <input type="submit" name="createAccount" value="Submit">&nbsp;&nbsp;



</div>
</form>
```

componentname.php

```
class RepeaterName extends ComponentBase
{

    public function componentDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'ReapeterName',
            'description' => 'Name.'
        ];
    }



    public function onEnter()
    {
        $input = post();

        log::info($input);

        $contact = new RepeaterModel();
        $instArr = [];

        $instArr['innername'] = [];
        for($i=0; $i<=5; $i++)
        {

            if(isset( $input['name'.$i])) {
                $instArr['innername'][] = $input['name'.$i];

            }
        }
        Log::info(json_encode($instArr));
        $contact->name =json_encode($instArr);


        //$contact->name=Input::post('name');

        $contact->save();

        Log::info($contact);

    }

}


?>
```

modelname.php

```
protected $jsonable = ['name'];
```

i want to show the inputs comes from frontend which is multiple name which must be save in json format because i want to show that imput in repaeter control whose name is 'name' and it have text control in it named 'innername' so is there any solution to show inputs at backend form

Comment: See how repeater control works in OctoberCMS - http://watch-learn.com/video-tutorials/making-websites-with-october-cms-part-12-repeater-field Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

yeahhh, i solved actually it was my mistake i use json_encode at componentName.php which is wrong because we already use $jsonable at model so passing json_encode () directly pass array where data is store

componentName.php

```
 public function onEnter()
    {
        $input = post();

      //  log::info($input);

        $contact = new RepeaterModel();
        $instArr = [];


        for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
        {

            $obj = [];
            if(isset( $input['name'.$i])) {
                $obj['innername'] = $input['name'.$i];

            }
            if(isset( $input['addr'.$i])) {
                $obj['inneraddr'] = $input['addr'.$i];

            }
            if(!empty($obj))
                $instArr[] = $obj;
        }

      $contact->fname=$instArr;

$contact->age=$input['age'];

        $contact->save();

        Log::info($contact);

    }

}
```